# How do i get only PID of postgres.exe from the first row of output

Tags: windows, postgresql, powershell, cmd, command-prompt

I am using this command-

```
tasklist /FI "ImageName eq postgres.exe"
```

this is the output I am getting-

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
postgres.exe                  2300 Services                   0     19,752 K
postgres.exe                  2932 Services                   0      6,324 K
postgres.exe                  2992 Services                   0      8,660 K
postgres.exe                  3000 Services                   0      8,256 K
postgres.exe                  3008 Services                   0     11,128 K
postgres.exe                  3016 Services                   0      8,120 K
postgres.exe                  3024 Services                   0      7,756 K
postgres.exe                  3032 Services                   0      7,732 K
postgres.exe                  1684 Services                   0     20,732 K
```

Comment: You going to make it yourself pretty difficult using external commands like `postgret.exe`, you better use a native PowerShell command like [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process) for this.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do same with PowerShell

Comment: `(get-process postgres)[0].id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the comment and question.

```bsh
(Get-Process postgres)[0].ID
```

`Get-Process` get's all running processes with name postgres

`[0]` grabs the first row

`.ID` grabs the PID property